# Convert Guava ListMultimap to Java Map

Tags: java, guava, multimap, apache-commons-collection

Guava `MultiMap` has implementations `ImmutableListMultimap` and `ImmutableSetMultimap`. Given that I have created an `ImmutableListMultimap<String, Anything>` instance, how can I convert that into a `java.util.Map<String, List<Anything>>`?

The `asMap()` method return a `java.util.Map<String, Collection<Anything>>`, but that cannot be cast to `java.util.Map<String, List<Anything>>`.

The best I have now is

```
 final Map<String, Collection<Anything>> listMultimap = multimap.asMap();
 // convert to Map<String, List<>>
 final Map<String, List<Anything>> listMap = listMultimap.entrySet().stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  Map.Entry::getKey, 
                  e -> (List<Anything>) e.getValue()));
```

but that does not look ideal. Given that the instance variable is of type ListMultimap, shouldn't there be a convenient method to represent it as a `Map<..., List>`?

Apache commons-collections `ArrayListValuedHashMap` has the same issue.

Comment: Do you really need this to be `List<A>`, cannot work with `Collection<A>`?

Comment: It would make the code look much cleaner. Of course, for reasons of algorithmic correctness, it does not change whether a List is declared as Collection. Except for the specific methods like indexed accessors. So I could downcast the contained values n every use or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ListMultimap.asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap--) docs mention

> Note: The returned map's values are guaranteed to be of type `List`. To obtain this map with the more specific generic type `Map<K, List<V>>`, call `Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)` instead.

So just use one of static [helper methods for this in `Multimaps`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap-com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap-) which:

> Returns `multimap.asMap()`, with its type corrected from `Map<K, Collection<V>>` to `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Comment: IDE showed javadoc of ImmutableMap instead, which sadly does not have that documentation.